# Constraints in routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a constraint:

```
get "test/:test_val" => "home#test", constraints: { test_val: /\d{4}/ }
```

I need it to accept only 4 digits. However, it doesn't seem to work because there's no error being thrown due to this constraint. What's up with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is absolutely correct and should work as it's working for me(I get these errors when I change my number of digits in route)-

routes I defined in my app:

```
get 'users/:id', to: 'users#show', constraints: { id: /\d{4}/ }
```

Error I get:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with id=1234
```

Which means it is working while won't recognize the route if digits are more or less than 4:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/users/123456"
```

So, are you sure that you don't have any other route defined with `/test/:test_val` above this route which is overriding this one?

Also note that as @Amadan mentioned in his answer to use regexp anchors. Which will not work. You can find this documented in [Rails routing from outside in guide section: 3.8 Segment Constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints). It clearly says:

> :constraints takes regular expressions with the restriction that
>   regexp anchors can't be used. For example, the following route will
>   not work:

```
get '/:id', to: 'posts#show', constraints: {id: /^\d/}
```

> However, note that you don't need to use anchors because all routes are anchored at the start.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`/\d{4}/` will test if there are four consecutive digits anywhere in the string. Thus, `123456789` matches, because `1234` satisfies the test. You probably want to anchor the start and the end of the regular expression:

```
/^\d{4}$/
```

Comment: it still throws the same error which is an invalid parameter in a function, so this constraint isn't  working because it allow the parameter to reach the function where it's invalid. I want to capture it earlier, of course